# ggplot2 histogram mean line with value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created histogram like this:

```
hist(parted[,name], col="steelblue", addMeanLine=TRUE, meanLineColor="red")
```

And I want to add label with value of mean. Is it possible?

Comment: The title says `ggplot2`, but the code uses base `hist`. Do you want a `base` histogram or `ggplot2` histogram?

Comment: Generally it's not a good recommended to invent your own arguments. If you run that code above you will get errors. In `base` you could use `abline(h=mean(parted[,name]))` or `text(0, 5, round(parted[,name], 2))`. Change to position to suit your needs